# How to make django allauth email verification a 5 step proceess?

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I have implemented Django allauth in my application. The user registers on the website, a confirmation email is sent, he clicks on it and can use the application right away. However, I want it to be like -

1. User registers
2. Admin is notified
3. Admin approves/rejects
4. If he approves, then only a confirmation email should be sent.

How can I achieve this flow? This 5 step registration process is offered by https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-inspectional-registration but I would like to implement this in allauth.

Please give me some pointers. I would highly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the adapter.py file in allauth/socialaccount. Inherit the same to an app in your project.

Add this in settings file:

SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = "apps.appname.adapter.CustomSocialAccountAdapter"

customixe the save_user view in adapter.py. You can add your modification here(like email sending).